# Why OpenCart.v1.5.6.4 shows existing product images, but not new images?

Tags: php, opencart, image-upload

I've just installed OpenCart.v1.5.6.4 on my local machine and on server. The one on local works perfect, but the installed one on the server does not show images.

In adding a new product or editing, it shows the pictures that I upload, but in product lists, both in cpanel and interface, does not show any newly created product's image.

I almost have tried all suggestions of the following post, but none of them worked for me:

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=50534

My server is Arvixe.com (ASP.NET)

And the website: www.bizination.com. The website is in Persian and the newly added product is named as "dad" (without image).

Any idea how can I fix it?

Thanks for any kind help in advance!

Comment: Well I'd recommend avoiding Arvixe for hosting, especially if it's a shared host. As for the issue, it's almost certainly going to be a permissions issue on your image folder and it's subdirectories

Comment: @JayGilford: Thanks for your suggestion, but for now I have no other choice :(